# Type signature with private type

Tags: haskell, types

OK, so here's an obscure corner of the language:

Haskell allows you to export an identifier who's type signature mentions a type that is *not* exported. What exactly is the semantics of this?

For example, suppose I have

```
module Foobar (bar) where

data Foo = ...

bar :: String -> Foo
```

`Foo` is not exported, while `bar` is. The type of `bar` mentions `Foo`, though. Many programming languages wouldn't let you do this, but Haskell does.

So what now? It seems that I can call `bar`, but then can't do much with its result. I particular, I (presumably) cannot utter the name of the result type, which is kinda weird. Presumably if the module exported some functions that take `Foo` as input, I ought to be able to call those with my result as input... yet all the whole I can't say so in a type signature.

For sure, doing something like the above is not *a good idea*; I'm not proposing to do this in actual code. I'm just curious as to what it actually *does*.

Comment: As far as I can see, you have analyzed the situation correctly. You could call other functions taking a `Foo`, and you could call polymorphic functions, but you can't write type signatures mentioning the unexported name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be more interesting if Haskell were to forbid you from exporting types of your own which infer `Foo`s---this would make the situation here behave a bit more like existential typing which is A Good Idea for module systems.

Instead, the type information leaks. So does the instance information. For "instance" the following is unsafe

```
module Foo ( foo ) where

  data Foo ...
    deriving (Data, Typeable) -- for internal use

  foo :: Foo -> IO ()
```

since using `foo` will allow an "evil" user to unify `Data.Data.fromConstr ...` with `Foo` even if users are not supposed to be able to generate `Foo` values.

```
-- mkFoo :: Constr -> Foo       (except I have to let this be inferred)
mkFoo c = out where
  out     = fromConstr c
  ignored = foo out
```

Ultimately, I'd consider this to be a poor API. If you want to emphasize the use of a type without allowing the user to construct it, export the type.